# ngCordova linked contact

Tags: ionic-framework, ios9, ngcordova

I'm getting this crash

```
*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'A contact and its snapshot should both be non-unified.'
```

when trying to pick a contact using `$cordovaContacts.pickContact()`. The issue only happens when the picked contact is a linked one and it only occurs in iOS9.

Found [this workaround](https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/11354) but it's for native apps and not good due "bad privacy practice"

Anyone knows a solution when using ngCordova?

Comment: Did you find a fix for this? Thanks

Comment: Unfortunately nope. Please, let me know if you found something!
Thanks!